# Find outlines/ borders of label image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, label

I was wondering if there’s an easy way to convert a label matrix into a matrix where you have lines anywhere two labeled regions meet and zeros elsewhere so that you could basically superimpose the borders of regions on the original image from which the labels were generated as another visualization alternative to the popular label2rgb function.

The reason I ask is that I’m currently working on with some superpixel code, so I have many labeled regions (500 to 5,000). I’ve been using rgblabel to convert the superpixel labels to colored regions, turning hold on, then displaying them over the original image with 'AlphaData' turned down to make them semi-transparent. However, with so many regions, this can be hard to analyze visually and I think simple borders of the regions would work better. Thanks.

[EDIT] @O_O: I've attached a sample label matrix along with the target result although I'm now quite satisfied with Jonas's second suggestion. Will try method from user616736 as well in the next day. I've also [uploaded](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~ssilk083/label_matrix_borders.zip) the sample images in .mat format here in case anyone else wants to experiment with them.

Label Matrix:

[image: Label Matrix]

Desired Result:

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: Please provide an example picture if possible! I can't really visualize what you are asking.

Comment: both answers solve your problem, although user616736's is what i've used most often (simply because it's fewer lines, and the intent is clear)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to loop through all labels and eliminate all but the border, like this (where `lblImg` is your label matrix)

```
nLabels = max(lblImg(:));
for lbl = 1:nLabels
    currenObject = lblImg == lbl; %# find pixels belonging to current label
    lblImg(imerode(currentObject,strel('disk',1))) = 0; %# mask all but the border
end

imshow(label2rgb(lblImg))
```

**EDIT**

A faster method to find borders, is to use the gradient of the labeled image

```
[gx,gy] = gradient(lblImg);
lblImg((gx.^2+gy.^2)==0) = 0;

imshow(label2rgb(lblImg))
```

Comment: Thanks, that does what I want. It's just a lot slower than I'd like (took about 10 full seconds for a 3/4 MP image on my computer). I'd like to be able to do this on a series of label images in a loop, displaying them as I go for the user, so the delay makes this a bit cumbersome. I was really hoping there was some more built-in functionality for this in MATLAB that would execute faster.

Comment: Hi, this is a big improvement, thanks. I changed your code slightly so that right after your middle line, there's a line `lblImg(lblImg>0) = 1;` to make the resulting edge image binary. Is there a way to integrate that with the line  `lblImg((gx.^2+gy.^2)==0) = 0;` to roll them into one? It's a minor detail, so no worries if not. Thanks again.

Comment: @SSilk: Sure, you can write `lblImg = (lblImg > 0) & ((gx.^2+gy.^2)>0);`

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to the image processing toolbox (I assume you do, since you're dealing with label matrices), you can use the `edge` function. Here's a simple example

```
img = imread('rice.png');
imshow(img)
```

`rice.png` is Matlab's stock image, so you can run this code on your machine. The image looks like this.

[image]

Now get labelmatrix

```
bw = im2bw(img, graythresh(img)); 
cc = bwconncomp(bw);
lblMatrix = labelmatrix(cc);
imshow(lblMatrix)
```

`lblMatrix` looks like this

[image]

Now we get the edges of the label matrix. Here I've used the Laplacian of Gaussian method, but you can choose any other algorithm (see the help for more)

```
edgeMatrix=edges(lblMatrix,'log',0);
imshow(edgeMatrix)
```

[image]

This finds all edges that are larger than `0`, which is what you need. You can then manipulate this however you want in your processing and overlay on top of other figures. In practice, you need something slightly higher than zero, so that you don't get those little circles (which are just due to noise), and only recover what you want. You can tinker and adjust the threshold to something else, till you get it just right. Although this can be automated, I can't say much without knowing the actual problem. Anyway, this is just to get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Hi, I've uploaded a sample of a label matrix I'm working with (see original post). One thing that's unusual about it is that all the adjacent labeled regions border on one another. I haven't tried your method yet (will soon), but can you tell if it should work in my situation? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, it will. In that case, you might have to use 'roberts' instead of 'log'... The command would read `edgeMatrix=edges(lblMatrix,'roberts',0);` Here is what it looks like http://i.imgur.com/yUOEe.jpg

 This method also returns a binary map, so you can directly use it in your application. I would recommend going with `'roberts'` in general. I just used `'log'` off the top of my head as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Quick follow up:

I also posed this question on Steve Eddins' [blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/), and he [offered](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/04/14/relabeling-a-label-matrix/#comment-24002) a very quick way to find the edges of the label image:

```
region_borders = imdilate(lblImg,ones(3,3)) > imerode(lblImg,ones(3,3));
```

I like this option because my main reason for looking for the borders is for visualization purposes, and this gives somewhat thicker borders. Also, his function [`imoverlay`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10502) is a handy way to view the borders you've found on top of the original image that the labels were generated from.